# Unable to access R.raw

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

I know this has been posted many, many times, but none of those solutions seems to solve my problem.

I have added a 'raw' folder to my project and placed a file 'sound1.mp3' in it.
On refresh of the project the file is visible but can not be accessed.

I have cleaned the project (about a 100 times :-) )

deleted and put back the folder

checked the file is named in lower case

changed the file name in case i was using some reserved word (3 times)

checked that none of the files contain 'import android.R'

explicitly imported my project.R

tried to reference the file with com.example.myproject.R (FYI: that's not the actual code)

updated to the latest ADT bundle

closed and restarted eclispe and my PC more times than i can count

checked the XML - it's all auto generated and I haven't edited it

manually deleted the R.java file and rebuilt the project, it was recreated (it also runs provided I comment out the reference to the audio)

removed and reinstalled all the build tools

selected an older version of the build tools (i tried 18.1.1, 18.1, 18, 17 and 19)

created another example project - same problem

I'm stumped for ideas now, anything else I've not done or not found already?
Sorry to post such a common problem, it's just after 5 hours I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Please post your error log. Check the console view. Have you created the raw folder in res directory ?

Comment: "I have added a 'raw' folder to my project". Where? Hope it will be inside 'res' folder.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, yes the raw folder is inside Res...I'll check the error log.

Comment: ok, I cleaned out the error log and logcat, rebuiuld and they're empty....appologies I'm new to eclipse, android and java...a lot to learn in only 2 weeks so I'm probably doing that all wrong.

Comment: ok...logcat...filtered for my package...nothing in error log still:...apologies, to big to paste here

Comment: Problem log shows this:
raw cannot be resolved or is not a field SplashActivity.java /parkapp/src/com/vpa/parkapp line 20 Java Problem

Comment: Logcat link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vyv3m15xm5ci0jn/logcat.txt

Comment: I've decided to abandon eclipse, deleted and reinstalled and no joy...I'll try Android Studio and see if that suits me better. Thanks for your replies folks.

Comment: FYI: Worked in minutes in android studio...